# Annotate not returning the expected results

Tags: python, django, django-models, annotations, django-queryset

I have a model here as below:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False,)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    raised_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    cause = models.ForeignKey('Cause', on_delete=models.SET('cause not set'))
    ngo_id = models.ForeignKey('NGO', on_delete=models.SET('ngo not set'))
    zip = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
    reimagine_fees=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3,default=0.05)
    person_of_contact = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    summary = models.TextField(blank = False)
    story = models.TextField(blank = True)
    fb_description=models.CharField(max_length = 301,blank=True)
    tax_exemption_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    banner = models.TextField(blank=True)
    team_member_id = models.ForeignKey(Team_Member, on_delete=models.SET('team member not set'))
    project_page_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to filter the Project objects according to the percetages of funding, that is, the ratio of `raised_amount` and `total_amount`... I am using annotate for this. However, the filter isn't giving the results as I expected it to give. My filter queries are:

```
project_list = project_list.annotate(x=F('raised_amount')/F('total_amount')).exclude(x__gte=0.8)

project_list = project_list.annotate(x=F('raised_amount')/F('total_amount')).exclude(x__lte=0.2)

project_list = project_list.annotate(x=F('raised_amount')/F('total_amount')).exclude(x__lte=1, end_date__gte=datetime.date.today())
```

`project_list` is a queryset of all the `Project` objects.

Help me here...

Comment: what were you expecting?

Comment: ... and how does that differ from what you actually got?

Comment: if project_list is a dictionary why are you trying to call annotate on it? You should be calling annotate on a QuerySet

Comment: sorry, it was already a queryset... typo, my bad... I have rectified the question

Comment: I was expecting it to display projects according to the calcuations I've added in the filter obviously... But it was either returning no objects or incorrect objects in some of the cases

Answer (score 0):

```
projects = Project.objects.all() # projects is a queryset

project_list = projects.annotate(x=F('raised_amount')/F('total_amount')).exclude(x__gte=0.8)
```

try all of you annotation on queryset, rather than on dictionary.